# Is there a plugin for FireFox to simulate IE 6 HTML rendering?

Tags: firefox, plugin, internet-explorer-6

Is there a plugin for FireFox that will allow me to view a website as if I was looking at it in IE 6?

I have a login portal on the site built with ASP, and users with IE6 cannot display it. I have added a message that shows up only if the user is running IE6 saying their browser needs updating to display this website correctly.

I cannot view this or check it works as I do not have IE 6 or a plugin that behaves like IE 6

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a plugin for FireFox that will allow me to view a website as if I was looking at it in IE 6?

Unfortunately not, however there are a great number of on-line services that you can use for testing, or you could also install a stand-alone version of IE6 for testing on your own PC.

On-line renderers:
http://netrenderer.com/
http://browsershots.org/
http://www.browsercam.com/

Stand-alone versions of Internet Explorer:
http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

The benefit of an on-line renderer is that if it's just a display issue you wish to see in action, it requires the least amount of effort and is generally quite quick to test out.

The benefit of the stand-alone solution is that you'll be able to actually click on things and practically use the site as you would in any other browser which might uncover specific problems that only occur due to a particular user interaction (clicking on a link or button that's being manipulated via JavaScript, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend getting vmware and creating a virtual but [IETab+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab/) is what you're looking for

Comment: IETab+ only embeds the version of Internet Explorer you happen to have installed on your PC. The OP doesn't have **IE6** so this plugin would unfortunately not be of much help.

Comment: As I said, I prefer and recommend a virtual computer for this, it's the only thing that really works properly.